# Modifying the definition of a prime ideal in a commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

According to JOSEPH A.GALLAIN EDITION 8th

> A prime ideal $A$ of a commutative ring $R$ is a proper ideal of $R$ such that $a, b \in R$ and $ab \in A$ imply $a \in A$ or $b \in A$.

I am confused about what we may conclude after we change the above definition to be  as follows: if $a,b \in R$ then $ab \in A$ implies *both* $\,a,b\in A$. Does this mean that $A$ will not be a proper ideal?

Since $a,b$ are arbitrary then $ab \in A$ implies $a,b \in A$ then $A=R$.

But I am confused if we choose $a,b$ from $A$ then $a,b$ are in $R$ and in $A$ but can I choose $a,b$ in this way !

Please help me to reach the other side of river !

Comment: Are you assuming $R$ has a $1$? If so, then let $a = 1$ and $b \in A$ be an arbitrary element. Then if $ab \in A$ implies $a,b \in A$ you would conclude that $1 \in A$, hence $A = R$.

Comment: You are correct. Your new condition can only be satisfied if the ideal is the ring. This can be seen by noticing that $0\in A$, which implies that $0\cdot 1\in A$, so $1\in A$.

Comment: No R could be any Ring

Comment: This property cannot be true for a proper ideal. Indeed; if $a\in A$, then $1\cdot a=a\in A$, yet $1\notin A$ and a prime ideal is by definition a *proper*   ideal.

Comment: @AdeshSharma Bungo is asking whether your definition of ring mandates the existence of a multiplicative inverse. However, I've never seen a definition of a commutative rng, so I assume that this is probably given.

Comment: @DonThousand I also assume so, but I'm not familiar with Gallian.

Comment: Okay got it thank you!

Comment: @DonThousand yeah sorry I read the comment wrong but I got my answer !

Comment: Note that the proofs above also work for non-unital rings (the colloquial "rng" Don mentioned).  Just replace $1$ in the comments with an arbitrary $r \in R$

Answer (score 1):

Try and think where the definition of prime ideal comes from.

A prime number $p$ satisfies the property “if $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$”.

You seem to be interested in the set of all positive integers $s$ that satisfy

> if $s$ divides $ab$, then $s$ divides $a$ and $b$

Well, this set is quite small, because only $1$ satisfies the requirement: indeed, for every $a$, $p$ divides $ap$.

---

Let's generalize: you should be able to see the similarity in the argument.

Let now $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$ (no unit element required) such that

> for all $a,b\in R$, if $ab\in I$ then $a\in I$ and $b\in I$

Take $a\in I$; then, for every $b\in R$, $ab\in I$, forcing $b\in I$.